# PDF Dropdown List that "auto-populates" Fields with values [using PDF X-Change Editor]?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation

I would like to ask the gurus lurking about on how to create a PDF Table with a Dropdown List that "auto-populates" (I do not know if that is the proper term...) fields with the appropriate values from the Dropdown List. I have already managed to create the table AND the dropdown lists (yay me!). But I would like it to fill up the appropriate columns for the "Rate" and "Hours" columns when I pick from the dropdown menu.

I do not know a single thing about JavaScript but I am aware that is most likely what I need to implement to do what I want to do.

Here is a picture to help visualize what I mean:
[PDF Table with Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilarN.png)

I am using PDF-XChange Editor. If we can do the above without having to involve JavaScript, then that would be a plus. If not, I will take what I can get (beggars can't be choosers lol). My many thanks as always!

Comment: Please describe fill it up. From where will get the content? External to the PDF?

Comment: Pardon me! I will clarify! In the table (image attached), I would like the dropdown list column "Support" to fill values in the "NDIS Rate" and "Hours or Funds". For example I pick an item from the drop down list: "Support: Item 1" should then show "NDIS Rate: $5.00" and then "Hours or Funds: 1.5hrs". Pick Item 2 in the Support Column dropdown list should have a different output on both columns and so on and so forth. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this one. If a PDF has a javascript embedded and created using Adobe, the Javascipt cannot be viewed by any other editor BUT Adobe. So, buy a lisence for Adobe DC Pro and edit the PDF with it.

All of the request above can be done using the Adobe PDF Form editor alongside the Javascript tool inside it.